# simple and uniform convergence of $ \sum ( x+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{x}{n}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

It's my first post in this forum ! Hello ! (I have a very bad english sorry in advance...) I come with an exercice that I can not solve. I hope you can help me...
Q1 : simple and uniform convergence of $ \sum ( x+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{x}{n}} $

Here my guess and what I have done the convergence is |x|< 1 (that I didn't proved just guessed)
I tried limited development it didn't worked.

Thank you for reading !

Comment: It is certainly not uniform over the interval.  However I believe it is uniform over $|X|\lt 1-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Comment: Hi ! Why do you have this belives ? Any methods? I'm still working on it and didn't even proved the simple convergence lol
Ty for for the answer !

Comment: The power is not defined as  a real num ber for $x<0$.

Comment: hi ! so : let  x >0 then $\left ( x+\frac{1}{n} \right )^{(n+\frac{x}{n})} = e^{((n+ \frac{x}{n})(ln(x)+ln(1+\frac{1}{xn}))}=e^{((n+ \frac{x}{n})(ln(x)+\frac{1}{xn}+o(\frac{1}{n})))}$ this is where i'm stuck ty for you answer !

Comment: Use the $(\epsilon,\delta)$ convergence test at $x=1-a$.  The same $(\epsilon,\delta)$ pair will apply for interval $0\le x\le 1-a$.  Therefore uniform.

Comment: Hey ty for the answer, I don't understand what do you mean, can you explain me plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the convergence, using the ratio test, let
$$a_n=\left( x+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+\frac{x}{n}}\implies \log(a_n)=\left(n+\frac{x}{n}\right) \log \left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Now, using Taylor series for large values of $n$
$$\log(a_n)=n \log (x)+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2x^3 \log (x)-1}{2x^2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Apply it twice and continue with Taylor series
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=\log (x)+\frac{1-2x^3 \log
   (x)}{2x^2n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1} } {a_n}=\exp\big(\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n) \big)=x+\frac{1-2 x^3 \log (x)}{2 n^2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: Hi ! Ty for the answer it's a pleasure to read so many answer ! 
I have a doubt about your second term in the end, because : 
$e^{log(x)+\frac{1-2x^3log(x)}{2x^2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})}=xe^{\frac{1-2x^3log(x)}{2x^2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})}$

Comment: but still : $\left |  xe^{\frac{1-2x^3log(x)}{2x^2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})}\right |\underset{+\infty}{\rightarrow} \left |   x\right |$

Comment: @Loca. I do confirm the result. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: This site is amazing ! Ty for your help all ! <3

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to apply the $n$-root test.

To have powers well defined, assume $x\geq0$.
Let $a_n(x)=\Big(x+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{n+\tfrac{x}{n}}=x^{n}x^{x/n}\Big(1+\frac{1}{xn}\Big)^n\Big(1+\frac{1}{xn}\Big)^{x/n}$. Then
$$
|a_n(x)|^{1/n}=|x||x|^{x/n^2}\Big|1+\frac{1}{xn}\Big|\Big|1+\frac{1}{nx}\Big|^{x/n^2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}|x|
$$

Hence, as you suspected, convergence holds for $0<x<1$ and uniform convergence occurs in compact subsets of $(0,1)$. Some details are left for the OP.

Comment: Great idea ! ty ! Have all a nice day !